# Not able to delete a Row which has a timestamp Long.MAX_VALUE from Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, crud, hbase-shell

Somehow I ended up adding a row to `Hbase` with timestamp as `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Now Either not able to `put` with less than that `Long.MAX_VALUE` to the same `key` or `delete` that inserted row.

**What cause this issue**

Once I succesfully added this row (For some curiosity). Is it bad to add a `timestamp` value like this?

```
mm21000000000:422021000000000     column=s:fe:k, timestamp=9223370481975138807, value=m21000000000
mm21000000000:422021000000000     column=s:fe:m21000000000, timestamp=9223370481975138807, value=\x01
```

Now, If I try to add one more column to same row like this without `timestamp` or less than the `timestamp` as `< Long.MAX_VALUE`, it won't working. Of course If I add a new `row` with diff `key` it works.

```
put 'ue_combo','mm21000000000:422021000000000','s:le:k','3422021000000000' // I'll be adding this via JAVA
//Briefly
put.addColumn("s".getBytes(), "le:k".getBytes(), ts, "3422021000000000".getBytes()); //ts is timestamp
```

Finally decided to get rid of that row and tried deleting that row using `key` value and also used `ROWPREFIXFILTER` as shown below

```
deleteall 'table_name', 'mm21000000000:422021000000000'
deleteall 'table_name', {ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'mm'}
```

**Not at all deleting**

Solution via shell command or through Hbase APIs via `JAVA` codebase will help. Also able to figure the issue but not able to understand it thoroughly. Is `Hbase` understanding that the row added with `timestamp` as `Long.MAX_VALUE` will be added in future time? `Hbase` only allow in increasing ordered `timestamp` then meaning once a maxed `timestamp` is stored less than that `timestamp` cannot be inserted?

I found this [mail-archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@hbase.apache.org/msg44599.html), didn't understood much but I think he tries to overriding the `Hbase` code. That's not possible in my case.

If you need anything extra, please mention in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this HBase behaviour and the HBase concepts that lead to it, the main problem is the Long.MAX_VALUE is a special value, that will be changed to the current time on the server side.

By design, Long.MAX_VALUE should not be used as a timestamp for any row, but HBase does not provide any protection to avoid it.

If you discover HBase client code, e.g. [Put](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/cf02edbb1cea37a9a1cc4a64ff50f77a86955e5c/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.java#L51), you can see using HConstants.LATEST_TIMESTAMP as the default timestamp for every put. Which means that the server should use the current timestamp.

```
  public Put(byte [] row) {
    this(row, HConstants.LATEST_TIMESTAMP);
  }
```

Also, you can read [this comment](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blame/cf02edbb1cea37a9a1cc4a64ff50f77a86955e5c/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HConstants.java#L644) for LATEST_TIMESTAMP constant with a detailed description of deleting rows.

The solution provided in the mailing-archive is based on manually rewriting HFile with the delete marker for the desired row. Also, it contains a gist with an example of code: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@hbase.apache.org/msg44615.html